# How to merge two datasets with different shape (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, merge, size

I want to merge two datasets of different sizes. Ex.

```
df = {'identifier': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
        'Income': [50,40,70,50,60,30],
        }
df2= {'identifier': [1,2],
        'Rent': [150,300],
        }
```

With the following output:

```
df3={'identifier': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
     'Income': [50,40,70,50,60,30],
     'Rent': [150,150,150,300,300,300],
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an inner join with [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with the default inner join option.

**Data Setup**

```
df = {'identifier': [1,1,1,2,2,2],
        'Income': [50,40,70,50,60,30],
        }
df2= {'identifier': [1,2],
        'Rent': [150,300],
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(df)    
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
```

**Main Code:**

```
df3 = df.merge(df2, on='identifier')
```

**Result:**

```
print(df3)

   identifier  Income  Rent
0           1      50   150
1           1      40   150
2           1      70   150
3           2      50   300
4           2      60   300
5           2      30   300
```

Answer (score 1):

[df_merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```
  df.merge(df2, on='identifier')
```